# Binding error between a ContentView property and a ViewModel's object property - why?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

I am working on a MAUI application in MVVM, and I am getting binding errors (when running the app and navigating to the page in question) which I do not understand. Here is what I am doing:

In the page I am using the ProgressBar control and binding its Progress property to the property of an object defined in the ViewModel which is the BindingContext of the page:

```
<tt:ProgressBar Progress="{Binding SessionProgression.ProgressionRatio}" />
```

The ViewModel property definition:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private TimeProgression _sessionProgression = new TimeProgression();
```

And the object in question's class definition (the rest of the class updates the property value and calls OnPropertyChanged("TimeProgression") but I have not included that for clarity):

```
public sealed class TimeProgression : ObservableObject
{
    public double ProgressionRatio { get; private set; }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error 127 TimeProgression ProgressionRatio    ProgressBar.Progress    Double  'ProgressionRatio'
> property not found on 'TimerToolkit.Models.TimeProgression', target
> property: 'TimerToolkit.Controls.ProgressBar.Progress'

Please note that if I put the ProgressionRatio property inside my ViewModel instead of inside the TimeProgression instance of my ViewModel, no binding error occurs. And in both case the correct value is resolved at run-time.

What am I missing here? Thanks for taking the time to read me.

**EDIT:**

I have further troubleshooted the issue and here is the culprit:

```
public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
{
    get => _elapsedTime;
    set
    {
        if (_elapsedTime != value)
        {
            _elapsedTime = value;
            ProgressionRatio = Math.Clamp(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds / Duration.TotalSeconds, 0, 1);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ElapsedTime));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProgressionRatio));
        }
    }
}

public double ProgressionRatio { get; private set; }

public void AddElapsedSeconds(int seconds)
{
    ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
}
```

-> It seems that assigning a new value to ProgressionRatio causes a binding failure in the View. The view is correctly updated with the new value however.

You could reproduce this behavior simply by adding a button on the page and assign its Clicked event like so:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MainPageViewModel)BindingContext).SessionProgression.AddElapsedSeconds(1);
}
```

Comment: Do you put ```tt:ProgressBar``` in a DataTemplate or use any compiled bindings? Could you please share more code about xaml file?

Comment: To be more specific, I try making a demo below but your code works well on m side. May I ask for your patience to check my answer below if there is anything I haven't considered?

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Thanks a lot for getting back to me, and my apologizes for the delay I did try to get back to you earlier but didn't manage to isolate the issue as your code sample is working perfectly fine indeed. I have just done that and I edited the question with the info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made a demo based on your code but still cannot reproduce. I have updated my answer. May I ask for your patience to check my answer if I missed  anything?

Comment: So may I ask what is ```tt:ProgressBar```? Is it from any other third-party Nuget?

Comment: tt:ProgressBar is indeed causing the issue, I tried with the official ProgressBar control and no binding errors occured. It is a control that I have copied and adapted to my needs originally from this library (not maintained anymore): https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/AlohaKit.Controls - I have set up a basic demo project reproducing the issue and where you can see the ProgressBar class: https://github.com/BeepBeepBopBop/BindingIssuesDemo/blob/main/ProgressBar.cs

Comment: I download your link above but your demo project works very well on my side.

Comment: Did it throw any error? You could try updating the Visual Studio (or for mac) 2022.

Comment: It does not throw any exception but it results in a binding failure, in the "XAML Binding Failures" window. One more error is reported every time the button is clicked. I tried updating VS Studio 2022 (Community) to the latest version. The error is 'ProgressionRatio' property not found on 'DemoApp.TimeProgression', target property: 'DemoApp.ProgressBar.Progress I am still relatively inexperienced with MAUI and XAML in general so I am not sure how important those kind of errors are

Comment: Okay I saw the warning. In ```ProgressBar.cs```, we set the **BindingMode.TwoWay** which cause the warning. I think for this case, you could set **BindingMode.OneWay** or just delete it.

Comment: Oh that was it, silly mistake TwoWay definitely does not make sense in that context, thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updates

I am so glad that we finally found the cause of the question.

In the `BindableProperty` **ProgressProperty**, it set the BindingMode to TwoWay, which makes no sense in this context and causes the warning.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Progress), typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBarDrawable), 0.0, BindingMode.TwoWay, ...
```

The solution is to set it as `BindingMode.OneWay` or no need set it(The default is OneWay).

---

I made a demo to test your code,

Here is the XAML file, I add a button behind the ProgressBar,

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Padding="30,0"
        Spacing="25">

        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

        <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding SessionProgression.ProgressionRatio}" />
        <Button Text="CLICK ME" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Set the BindingContext in code behind, and add the Button click handler,

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}

void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ((MainPageViewModel)BindingContext).SessionProgression.AddElapsedSeconds(1);

}
```

And define the ViewModel like this,

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private TimeProgression _sessionProgression = new TimeProgression();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        

    }
}
```

Give the `ProgressionRatio` an initial value to 0.3,

```
public sealed class TimeProgression : ObservableObject
{
    public double ProgressionRatio { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
    private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
    {
        get => _elapsedTime;
        set
        {
            if (_elapsedTime != value)
            {
                _elapsedTime = value;
                ProgressionRatio = Math.Clamp(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds / Duration.TotalSeconds, 0, 1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ElapsedTime));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProgressionRatio));
            }
        }
    }
    public void AddElapsedSeconds(int seconds)
    {
        ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    }

    public TimeProgression()
    {
        //ProgressionRatio = 0.5;
        ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    }
}
```

Here is the effect, each time we click the button, the progress bar will change.

[image]